# arrangement of arrays indices from minimum to maximum

Tags: java, arrays

I want to take the arrangement of numbers in array from minimum value to maximum value. For example if I insert 5 16 4 12 26 and I stored them in array [5,16,4,12,26], I want to order array from minimum to maximum and store the indexes in array like this [1,3,0,2,4]

```
Integer [] key = {5,16,4,12,26};
Integer [] orderedkey = key.clone();
Arrays.sort(orderedkey);
List <Integer> x = Arrays.asList(orderedkey);
for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(x.indexOf(i))
}
```

Comment: Your code is printing `1, 3, 0, 2, 4`, right?

Comment: no : `-1 -1 -1 -1 0`

Comment: no my code print -1 -1 -1  0 1

Comment: `x.indexOf(i)` should be `x.indexOf(key[i])`

Answer (score 1):

You could put items in sorted set and then count number of predecessors. This only works if values are unique.

```
final Integer[] key = {5, 16, 4, 12, 26};
final NavigableSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(key));
final Integer[] orderedKey = new Integer[key.length];
for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
    orderedKey[i] = set.headSet(key[i]/*, true*/).size();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(orderedKey));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `List.indexOf()` within a `[1..n]` for loop is `O(n^2)`. If `n` is not too big, this is OK.

However, there's another approach which is `O(nlogn)`:

```
Integer[] key = { 5, 16, 4, 12, 26 };

TreeMap<Integer, Integer> orderedKey = new TreeMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
    orderedKey.put(key[i], i);
}
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>(orderedKey.values());

TreeMap<Integer, Integer> orderedIndexes = new TreeMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    orderedIndexes.put(x.get(i), i);
}

List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(orderedIndexes.values());

System.out.println(result); // [1, 3, 0, 2, 4]
```

This solution relies on Java's [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which is a map that keeps its entries ordered by its keys *natural order*.

Two `TreeMap`s are needed to accomplish what you want. The first one would map the values to their indexes, while the second one would map the indexes of the ordered values to a range `[1..n]`.

As both maps are ordered by its keys, when we ask for its `values()` to the second map, we get the indexes in the desired ordered.